# Why table elements are nonStringifiable when vue's compiler stringify hoist?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning and studying `@vue/compier-dom` and now i have a question about why table elements are nonStringifiable.

```js
const isNonStringifiable = /*#__PURE__*/ makeMap(
  `caption,thead,tr,th,tbody,td,tfoot,colgroup,col`
)
// ...ignore others
if (node.type === NodeTypes.ELEMENT && isNonStringifiable(node.tag)) {
  return false
}
```

the stringifiable elements can be easily inserted into wrapper dom by using `innerHTML`. And this can improve performance.

Can someone answer my question?

I had searched in browser but no relevant.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am sorry for my humble description, but the context i had mentioned above is a bit complicated. And now i knew that it is a compatibility issues of `IE6 - IE9` to use `Node.innerHTML`. @YestheCia

Answer (score -1):

I had got the reply of vue's participator
link: https://github.com/vuejs/core/commit/a938b61edca63c1f03f99b85de3f2a3a519268e6
and now i know that it will cause error when use `innerHTML` to insert `table elements` into `warpper dom`.
such as

```js
const table = document.getElementById('table');
table.innerHTML = `<tr><td>123</td></tr>`
```

this will cause error:
`IE9：Invalid target element for this operation.`
`IE6-8：Unknown runtime error`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).